# Desempenho - Separar tabelas de log ou deixar no mesmo banco

Tags: php, mysql, desempenho, tabela-banco-de-dados, log

tudo joia?

Eu tenho um banco de dados mysql com aproximadamente 180mb de tamanho. Cada mês a aplicação cria automaticamente uma nova tabela com logs de acessos e ações, que em 14 meses estão totalizando 80mb de espaço em disco.

No meu caso específico, por alguns motivos, acho mais interessante criar um novo banco apenas para os logs, mas em questão de desempenho e estabilidade (em caso de muitas requisições ao mesmo tempo), o que é melhor? Manter tudo junto no mesmo banco, ou colocar as tabelas de log em um banco novo?

Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Também tenho esse questionamento. Inclusive trabalho com dois clientes cujos os bancos de logos estão sobrecarregados.

Comment: O log é o mecanismo de registro de dados e eventos de um sistema. Em caso de falha o log é utilizado como ferramenta de orientação ao reparo. Se o banco de dados for catastroficamente danificado e não puder ser restaurado por si e então ter que lançar mão de um bkp obsoleto. Como fariam para restaurar o sistema do seu contratante as condições atuais já que o log foi perdido junto do banco de dados(por estar incluso nele)?

Answer (score 0):

Olá, creio que manter os logs em mesmo database se torne melhor na questão de separar empresa ou aplicativos através deles.
Mas se sua preocupação é ganhar armazenamento, recomendo realizar backups destas informações e depois de confirmadas de que estão seguras, realizar o `TRUNCATE`